# how to increase multi values with mongodb

Tags: mongodb

e.g, I have 3 documents,
`{"_id" : 1, "tags" : [1,2]}` and
`{"_id" : 1, "tags" : [2,3]}` and
`{"_id" : 1, "tags" : [1,2,3,4]}`

After I insert them into mongodb, I wish the result is something like
`{"_id" : 1, "count" : [{tag:1, amount:2}, {tag:2, amount:3}, {tag:3, amount:2}, {tag:4, amount:1}]}` 
so I can easily get the tag total amount.

Is it possible to do this with only one upsert?

Let's explain this a little bit more. Here _id is user id, and tags is the tag he used. I ignore the content here, so the full document should be like `{"_id" : 1, "tags" :[1,2], "content": "some content"...}`. I want to show something like tagcloud for each user so I need to know the tags user used. I don't want to do the Aggerate $group or something else like Find, just want to generate these data while insert, so the query would be very simple. The idea is take more time at Insert but less on View.
Hope this make the question more clear.

Comment: Your question is not clear enough. Please edit your question and give some more info, so that you can get help.

Comment: _id is same for all documents?

Comment: It can be any one, so the update filter should be `"_id" : some_int_value`

Comment: _id, is the unique id for any given document in MongoDB. So it will always be unique. From your example, I understand that every time you are inserting some tag statistics, it is computing the amount and updating the document. So, this is not a query operation and hence it should be handled in code level.

Comment: Thank you. Pity that it can't be done with one upsert, it can't be done with one atomic operation.